# Easiest way to use a > 2TB internal hard disk in Windows XP 32-bit?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, 32-bit, gpt

I have an 3TB external disk and Windows XP 32 bit.
It works as a USB 2 disk with its enclosure, but I want to use it as an internal SATA disk.
I don't want to use it as a boot disk, only as a data disk.
I understand that normally I need GPT (GUID partition table), and then I can't use Windows XP 32 bit anymore. I would prefer to avoid this.
But what I did not understand by googling around is: can I partition the disk in 2 parts (so that each part is less than 2TB) with MBR and use it in Windows 32-bit? If yes, which tools do I need?

Comment: I've retagged this as the OS is important for the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [Paragon GPT Loader](http://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/components/gpt-loader/) ($19.95) which :

- Allows the use of all disk space on a 2.2TB+ drive under Windows XP
- Augments Windows XP by adding support for [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) disks

Or you could use the free [GIGABYTE 3TB+ Unlock Utility](http://gigabyte.com/microsite/276/3tb.html) to create two virtual drives on the disk : 2TB + 1TB, if your motherboard is on the supported list.

Comment: Or you could upgrade to a modern operating system to go with your modern hardware. :)  Good solutions, though - I've never used that particular app, but Paragon is legit.

Comment: Would pre-partitioning it into smaller partitions work?

Comment: @Moab: Not without GPT.

Comment: @harrymc: "Not without GPT" is the answer to my question, so I accept it. So I will get Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: That is the best way to go.

Comment: @harrymc, will Windows 7 32bit also do the trick?

Comment: @Rookie: This post was for XP. Windows 7 should have no problem with a large disk for both 32- and 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

OS Windows XP with 3TB Harddisk

the easy way is, http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/Utility.aspx

download the 3TB + unlock preinstall driver

then

download 3TB + Unlock

follow the instruction to setup